# Google maps with ajax

Tags: ajax, google-maps

I have a dynamic google map on my site with some custom markers. What I need to do is, when I click a specific marker I want a div to load underneath the map with the information about that marker (a shop) using Ajax.

Thanks a mil for your help,

Joanne

Answer (score 0):

You can bind event handler to your marker and execute ajax request to get marker information from server side script e.g. using jquery post.
Then on server side you can get necesswary info on the basis of some marker data like its position.

```
google.maps.event.addListener (marker, 'click', function(event) {
    var position  = marker.getPosition();
    $.post("getmarkerdata.php",{
        latitute: position.lat(),
        longitude: position.lng()  
    }),
    function(data){
        $(yourdiv).html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but i'm only starting and I need to do this for a project, would you be able to check my script and see if that would work ok with my code

Comment: your map is almost correct, except for just marker's icon property, you should pass not image path as a string there but google maps image object.
here I forked your code on jsfiddle to make it work http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/cXMMh/15/

Comment: aw .. your image was also ok, as of google maps v3 you can pass image as a string there. So it wasn't working just because of not included google maps js and invisible div, and all your js part is correct